# VBA For Loop - go longer than initially planned

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I would like to have an excel VBA For Loop that can go longer than I initially planned. For example:

```
Sub Test()
 LR = 10

 For i = 1 To LR
    Cells(i, 1).Value = 1
    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then
       LR = LR + 1
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Assuming there were contents in column 2/B, I am expecting to add 1 to LR at each iteration. I would expect this loop to continue to row 20. It is stopping on row 10 which is initially what is declared. How do I get around this issue, and have the loop go longer if I need to extend it based on a condition?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Can you explain what your use case is / what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Once it is set the for loop end cannot be changed.

Comment: You need to change to a Do While or Do Until loop

Comment: Note - if `LR` were actually changed in the for loop, then your loop would be an infinite one, it wouldn't stop at row 20. But as already pointed out, this sounds like an X-Y problem, we need more detail on what you actually are trying to do.

Comment: @BigBen you are correct that I had accidentally created an infinite loop. I edited the code to only increment LR up if some condition is true which I had intended to do before.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for clarifying that I need to use a Do While or Unitl Loop. It made sense to that I could modify LR inside of the loop, but obviously that was not working. I was able to accomplish the task using your advice. Thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Scott is correct.

UNTESTED

```
Sub Test()
LR = 10

Do Until LR = 20
    'Inside the loop you can use Exit Sub if a condition is meet before LR = 20
    If LR > 20 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    LR = LR + 1
Loop
End Sub
```